# How to use Promise.all with multiple Firestore queries

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, es6-promise

I know there are similar questions to this on stack overflow but thus far none have been able to help me get my code working.

I have a function that takes an id, and makes a call to firebase firestore to get all the documents in a "feedItems" collection. Each document contains two fields, a timestamp and a post ID. The function returns an array with each post object. This part of the code (getFeedItems below) works as expected.

The problem occurs in the next step. Once I have the array of post ID's, I then loop over the array and make a firestore query for each one, to get the actual post information. I know these queries are asynchronous, so I use Promise.all to wait for each promise to resolve before using the final array of post information.

However, I continue to receive "undefined" as a result of these looped queries. **Why?**

```
const useUpdateFeed = (uid) => {
  const [feed, setFeed] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    // getFeedItems returns an array of postIDs, and works as expected
    async function getFeedItems(uid) {
      const docRef = firestore
        .collection("feeds")
        .doc(uid)
        .collection("feedItems");
      const doc = await docRef.get();
      const feedItems = [];
      doc.forEach((item) => {
        feedItems.push({
          ...item.data(),
          id: item.id,
        });
      });
      return feedItems;
    }

    // getPosts is meant to take the array of post IDs, and return an array of the post objects
    async function getPosts(items) {
      console.log(items)
      const promises = [];

      items.forEach((item) => {
        const promise = firestore.collection("posts").doc(item.id).get();
        promises.push(promise);
      });

      const posts = [];
      await Promise.all(promises).then((results) => {
        results.forEach((result) => {
          const post = result.data();
          console.log(post); // this continues to log as "undefined". Why?
          posts.push(post);
        });
      });

      return posts;
    }

    (async () => {
      if (uid) {
        const feedItems = await getFeedItems(uid);
        const posts = await getPosts(feedItems);
        setFeed(posts);
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  return feed; // The final result is an array with a single "undefined" element
};
```

There are few things I have already verified on my own:

- My firestore queries work as expected when done one at a time (so there are not any bugs with the query structures themselves).
- This is a custom hook for React. I don't think my use of useState/useEffect is having any issue here, and I have tested the implementation of this hook with mock data.

**EDIT**: A console.log() of items was requested and has been added to the code snippet. I can confirm that the firestore documents that I am trying to access do exist, and have been successfully retrieved when called in individual queries (not in a loop).

Also, for simplicity the collection on Firestore currently only includes one post (with an ID of "ANkRFz2L7WQzA3ehcpDz", which can be seen in the console log output below.

**EDIT TWO**: To make the output clearer I have pasted it as an image below.

[image: log of function output]

Comment: Can you `console.log(items)` and check if documents with those IDs exists in Firestore? If it logs undefined then it's probably because the documents are msising

Comment: Pls also a log of `results`.

Comment: Hi @Dharmaraj, I have added the requested log. Also note that I have confirmed the documents with those IDs do exist in Firestore, and have successfully retrieved them with individual firebase queries. It is the loop of firebase queries that is not working.

Comment: What is the log of `[[Prototype]]: Array(0)` ? That looks like an empty array

Comment: @TarikHuber to make it clearer I have added an image of the console log instead. The log on line 81 relates to the console log of "items" within getPosts(). The log on line 93 refers to the console log within the Promise.all statement.

Comment: Great you could resolve the error :)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, this was human error. Looking at the console log output I realised there is a space in front of the document ID. Removing that on the backend made my code work.